# Automatic shutdown / hibernation after x minutes in suspend?

Tags: shutdown, hibernate, automation

I have an embedded battery powered device running Ubuntu and want to reduce power  consumption. The idea is that if a user does not use a device for ca. 30 min. then the device will automatically shutdown or hibernate.

Is it possible to automatically shut down or hibernate Ubuntu after spending x minutes in suspend?

Comment: What do you mean by "stand-by", no user input ?

Comment: I think he means suspend.

Answer (score 2):

Suspend is an hardware managed state, such function if available would need to be implemented at the BIOS level, or at least would require BIOS support.

Unless your BIOS provides such programmable function, no, it is not possible.

Comment: My BIOS supports this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [gshutdown](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gshutdown)   from the Software Center.

If the default options are not working, try changing from Edit>Preferences>Actions the "*autodetect*" option to "*custom command*", press  "*Turn off the computer*" and fill it with the  `shutdown -h now` command.

Comment: I am not looking for shutdown-timer-like tool. Is **gshutdown** able to recognize that system is in a suspend mode?

Comment: @tommyk  I don't know if this program is able to recognize the computers state.

Answer (score 0):

The installation here : http://gshutdown.tuxfamily.org/en/download.php works well (gshutdown_0.2-1_i386.deb)